# Почему Google по всем поисковым запросам ведет на одну страницу сайта?

Tags: seo, поиск, поисковые-системы

Какой бы запрос не делал, выводит только одну страницу. Подскажите, почему так?

Comment: @gold, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести, как она относится к программированию, что за код вы используете и т. д.

Comment: @eicto Проблема в том что, когда ищу какие то записи с сайта, гугл ведет на одну страницу, а другие игнорирует, выходит что все посетители попадают на одну страницу по всем запросам.

Comment: Возможно в индексе только главная. А остальные забанены.

Comment: @jMind подскажи, где посмотреть забаненные страницы ?

Comment: http://www.google.ru/advanced_search
Заполнить полет "Сайт или домен:", остальные поля оставить пустыми, нажать "Найти".
Можно будет увидеть сколько страниц в индексе.

Comment: Достаточно ввести в строку поиска запрос site:www.yourdomain.ru. Google выдаст список проиндексированных страниц.
Это для начала, чтобы убедиться, что Google имеет их в базе.

Answer (score 2):

[Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/) в помощь. Просмотрите разделы, отвечающие за индексацию, почитайте советы для получения оптимизации. Возможно, есть смысл в генерации файла sitemap для вашего сайта для улучшения положения индексации.

Пример эффективного использования sitemap (данные с одного из моих сайтов) - из 137-и страниц 136 проиндексированы и все доступны в результатах поиска.

[image]

Comment: @void а где там посмотреть раздел отвечающий за индексацию, у меня нету robot.txt и sitemap.xml, в остальном ошибок нету написано )

Comment: Файл sitemap желательно иметь - кашу маслом не испортить.

Но даже если его нет, то слева в меню, что на картинке, выше раскрытого - смотрим Google Index и там выбираем Index Status. Смотрим, сколько проиндексировано роботом поисковика.

Для всего остального (и самого подробного) надо в код вашего сайта интегрировать код [Google Analytics][1]. На сайте подробно расписано, как это сделать (все очень просто). С его помощью можно "видеть" всё и даже больше.


  [1]: http://www.google.ge/analytics/

Comment: @void Проиндексирвано 42, удаленных нету, Аналитика стоит, мониторю сайт )

Comment: Загляните в Search Appearance->HTML Improvements.

Проверьте на количество показателей:

- Duplicate meta descriptions
- Duplicate title tags

Это все влияет на уникальность индексации (робот должен "понимать", что каждая страница не про одно и то же).

Comment: @void вот там 42 повторяющихся метаописания, 29 повторяющихся заголовка, это потому что у всех страниц один <head> ?

Comment: @gold Это потому что многие ваши страницы имеют одинаковые записи в <title> и <meta>. И это есть нехорошо (насчет того как оптимизировать контент с этими тегами писать не буду - много текста и масса информации в том же самом Гугле).
Если на странице продается пылесос Bosch 12345 с турбонаддувом, то <title> должен иметь схожий текст, например, "Купить пылесос Bosch 12345 с турбонаддувом - Наш магазин", а не просто повторяющийся тэг "Наш магазин - самые выгодные цены" на каждой странице. Ну и т.д.

Comment: @gold Хотя, опять же, уникальное описание тэгов не значит, что сайт будет на первых позициях. У меня есть сайт, где многие страницы имеют одинаковое описание, но видны в поиске по контенту. Здесь двумя словами не описать тонкостей, но почитав материалы по оптимизации, можно добиться существенных(!) изменений.

Comment: @void примного благодарен, сделаю соответствующие изменения по сайту и почитай по оптимизаций )